# Is there a drag and drop Bootstrap UI editor like SilkUI for Visual Studio?

Tags: user-interface, editor, bootstrapping, outsystems

I just watched the video [here](https://labs.outsystems.net/silkui/#) and it appears that SilkUI is tied to Outsystems.

While I like the idea of the UI editor, is there something like this for Bootstrap, where I wouldn't be tied to a specific vendor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an independent tool for it .. 
[BootStrap Studio](https://bootstrapstudio.io)
you can try it:)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SILK UI is indeed meant to be used with OutSystems. It is part of the product.